# Prevent control disabling in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, controls

is there a way to make a control always enabled, so that if you set `Enabled = False` it has no effect?
I tried to add a handler to the EnabledChange event in this way:

```
AddHandler mybutton.EnabledChange, Sub() 
                                         mybutton.EnabledChange = True
                                   End Sub
```

but it causes a stackoverflow exception in a lot of situations, for example when you try to disable the control that contains the button. So is there another way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to create such a pitfall? Most of the time "magic" code is bad, you'll forget that it exists.

Comment: Don't add code.  Remove code.  In particular the code that sets the Enabled property to False :)  If it is not your code then there's a programmer that can help you out, it isn't very likely you'll find him here.

Comment: The problem is that my project is full of code where i disable a lot of controls within the same loop, so i have to add a condition to every loop to skip the disabling of that control. Since it's a special control that is added to every form i'm looking for a way to simply prevent that other code disable it

Comment: @mck89: Refactor your code to never trigger unnecessary work. In your case do not fire Enabled event if you don't want it to fire. Put the condition inside the loop, so if True, you will NOT set `Enabled = False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**

**Not within any realm of good coding practice**

- if you change it to enabled = false, it changes the property setting with that event.

What is the code issue, there will be a solution?

In the properties of the control, enabled =true. You don't need to write code for it. It's in the form design.

In response to your comment:

You can use the patch that matzone has selected.. personally, I am in favor of removing that particular control from the loop, and I've had issues with nested and endless loops in vb.net...I just prefer to have less unnecessary changes, within my program, just helps keep out the bugs. It means you've got to go through and ensure the code re-enabling the control is always called, whenever it is changed in the loop.. asking for errors if you ask me.. It may be more work in the short run, but would be better to select the control out in the first place. I've faced similar quandaries.

See link to MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enabled.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try change like this .. it's worked for me

```
Private Sub myButton_EnabledChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles myButton.EnabledChanged
        If Not myButton.Enabled Then myButton.Enabled = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately this causes the same stackoverflow exception when you try to disable the container of the control. I don't know why it happens, maybe it continues to set Enabled = False until it is respected by every control inside it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
Protected Overridable Sub cmdCancel_EnabledChanged(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdCancel.EnabledChanged

    If DirectCast(eventSender, TPDotnet.GUIControls.WinButtonEx).Enabled = False Then
        cmdCancel.Enabled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

The condition is handled correctly.